# How do I calculate the direction of an object in an windows form that should move to another object?

Tags: c#, game-physics

I am currently programming a small game in the windows form where I want to add an enemy which moves on a direct path to the player. I have the location of the player and the location of the enemy. I want to get the next location of the enemy 
which is only 3-5 pixels away of the old one. How do I calculate that?.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two `Location`. first for Source and second for Target.

you must suppose a iteration count. to say that Object must reach to a target at X steps.

so first thing is to calculate DeiffX and DiffY.

```
 double DiffX = (Target.X - Source.X);
 double DiffY = (Target.Y - Source.Y);
```

and at the next, we can say :

```
 int Step = (int)Math.Max(DiffY,DiffX);
```

for each iteration we must add some value to current location, so :

```
 double DeltaX = DiffX/Step;
 double DeltaY = DiffY/Step;
```

and at the final step :

```
 for (int i = 0; i<Step; i++)
 {
   Object.Location = new Point(Object.Location.X+ (int)DeltaX , Object.Location.Y + (int)DeltaY); 
 }
```

to calibrate the result :

```
 Object.Location = Target.Location;
```

(that's because our calculations has some decimals losts)